# Is there a way to load Shopify product images and other resources from an external server?

Tags: shopify

Shopify servers, especially cdn.shopify.com, are horribly slow at times.  Is there a way to optimize a store for a more consistent performance, or to link *PRODUCT images* from an external server so we don't have to use Shopify's slow CDN?

Edited for clarification: I want to know is if it's possible to have product images on an external server to bypass the high latency, slow Shopify CDN servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is 'no'. When you upload a product image Shopify copies it to their servers and CDN. There is no option to have it refer to your location instead. You can always request a feature request by submitting a support ticket.

You could get around the slow CDN by editing your theme's liquid templates and link to your images instead, however knowing Shopify I'd expect they are all over fixing the current CDN performance issues. Prior to a couple of weeks ago the performance was good.

Comment: We've contacted tech support and they did inform us that they've seen some performance issues and that they're working on the problem, so we'll just wait as suggested.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are certainly free to link any resource you want to any server you want. You could render all your shop images from S3 as easily as from your own Linode or Rackspace server. Nothing stops you from that. You just risk having poor performance due to all the latency you introduce asking for results from your server(s) and you lose all the nice Liquid tricks of your theme when dealing with assets like images.

Comment: Well, unless the CDN server gets a performance boost, there's little to lose in terms of latency (it's already bad).  But how do I make product images link from another server?  Every time I input an external URL, Shopify simply copies the image into CDN and changes the URL.

Comment: You are doing something horribly wrong then. If you reference an image  like this:


    `<img src="http://fizzbuzz.com/a/b/c/doggydoo.png" alt="nice"/>`

There is nothing but pure rendering from your fizzbuzz server. Shopify cannot rewrite that, it is all yours.

Comment: Let me try explaining the issue again: when an image is added to a product (I use an API call for that), the original URL is lost: a copy of the image is placed on the CDN server.  For example, I add the image http://myserver/myimage.jpg to product A, but when I edit the product's properties I see that the URL is now http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0162/3906/products/1011607140_medium.jpeg?24446.

Comment: You asked if there was a way to link to images on an external server. The answer is yes. Manually. End of story. Any use of Shopify Liquid asset manipulation code implies you accept the use of the Shopify CDN.